# Position image within div tag created by javascript?

Tags: javascript, image, html, position

I'm trying to position an image within a div tag which is generated by a javascript function. The problem is the position of the image is not 75 pixels from the left and 40 pixels from the top but instead its stuck at 0,0. Heres the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML lang="en">
<HEAD>  
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">    
</HEAD> 
<SCRIPT language = "JavaScript">
var my_div = null;
var newDiv = null; 
function creatediv(id, width, height, left, top, opacity) 
{ 
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div'); 
    newdiv.setAttribute('id', id);  

    newdiv.style.width =  width + "px";     
    newdiv.style.height = height + "px";     

    newdiv.style.position = "absolute";         
    newdiv.style.left = left + "px";         
    newdiv.style.top = top + "px";  

    newdiv.style.opacity = opacity;

    document.body.appendChild(newdiv); 

    my_div = document.getElementById(id);
    document.body.insertBefore(newdiv, my_div);
}
</SCRIPT>
<BODY onload="  creatediv('logo', 792, 1000, 75, 40, 1)">
<div  id = "logo" style=" z-index:1; font-size:200%; ">         
        <img src="some.gif" width="10%" height="10%">           
</div>
</BODY>
</html>
```

Comment: the image is not inside the div generated by javascript

Comment: Are you trying to create two divs?

Comment: But its enclosed within the div tags? Is there some other way to pass the image into the function `creatediv`? @ATOzTOA no just a div with an image within it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/steveukx/zv2tE/ The new div is at 75/40, but the image is still in the existing div, so remains at 0/0

Comment: @lost_with_coding What are you trying to do?

Comment: You're creating another div with empty content. If you want to place the image inside that div, you will have to look up the image in the DOM and insert it.

Comment: @ATOzTOA basically create a single DIV with an image in it.

Comment: @lost_with_coding Then you don't need to create a new div, just modify the original div attributes. See my answer...

Comment: @lost_with_coding Updated answer for your specific need...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: [**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/yTMTH/)

```
function updateDiv(id, width, height, left, top, opacity) 
{ 
    var mydiv = document.getElementById(id);
    mydiv.setAttribute('id', id);  

    mydiv.style.width =  width + "px";     
    mydiv.style.height = height + "px";     

    mydiv.style.position = "absolute"; 
    mydiv.style.left = left + "px";         
    mydiv.style.top = top + "px";  

    mydiv.style.opacity = opacity;
}
```

**Output**

```
<body onload="  updateDiv('logo', 792, 1000, 75, 40, 1)">
<div id="logo" style="z-index: 1; font-size: 200%; width: 792px; height: 1000px; position: absolute; left: 75px; top: 40px; opacity: 1;">         
        <img src="1.jpg" width="10%" height="10%">           
</div>  
</body>
```

---

**Update**

If you need to pass the image file as argument:

**HTML**

```
<BODY onload="  updateDiv('logo', 792, 1000, 75, 40, 1, '1.jpg')">
    <div  id = "logo" style=" z-index:1; font-size:200%; "></div>
</BODY>
```

**Javascript**

```
function updateDiv(id, width, height, left, top, opacity, imgSrc) 
{ 
    var mydiv = document.getElementById(id);
    mydiv.setAttribute('id', id);  

    mydiv.style.width =  width + "px";     
    mydiv.style.height = height + "px";     

    mydiv.style.position = "absolute"; 
    mydiv.style.left = left + "px";         
    mydiv.style.top = top + "px";  

    mydiv.style.opacity = opacity;

    mydiv.innerHTML = '<img src="' + imgSrc + '" width="10%" height="10%">';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to make the image is inside the div generated by javascript then you can use this code:

```
function creatediv(id, width, height, left, top, opacity, imageurl) 
{ 
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div'); 
    newdiv.setAttribute('id', id);  

    newdiv.style.width =  width + "px";     
    newdiv.style.height = height + "px";     

    newdiv.style.position = "absolute";         
    newdiv.style.left = left + "px";         
    newdiv.style.top = top + "px";  

    newdiv.style.opacity = opacity;

    newdiv.innerHTML='<img src="' + imageurl + '" width="10%" height="10%">';

    document.body.appendChild(newdiv); 

    my_div = document.getElementById(id);
    document.body.insertBefore(newdiv, my_div);
}
```

Comment: Is there some way to pass an argument into `function creatediv(id, width, height, left, top, opacity) ` and have this be dynamic `src="some.gif"`

Comment: This will create two divs with same id 'logo'. OP only needs one div.